# Filtering Nested array with linq

Tags: c#, json, linq

I have an array like this coming from API response and I want to filter by nested property products to returns product with only id 11

```
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "status": true
        },
        {
          "id": "14",
          "status": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "xyz",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "status": true
        },
        {
          "id": "28",
          "status": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "123",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "48",
          "status": null
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "456",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "status": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

the resulting output should look like this,

```
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "status": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "xyz",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "status": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "123",
      "products": []
    },
    {
      "name": "456",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "status": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I'm trying to return filter output with the C# LINQ method. but, getting an error when filtering a nested array with the following method

"Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"

```
assets.Select(asset => asset.products.Where(product => product.id == "11")).ToArray();
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting this error "Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type"

Comment: You need to put the error [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62272914/edit), not in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just remove all items from every `products` array, whose `id` doesn't equal `11`. Parse JSON to `JObject`, iterate over `assets` array, find `products` with `id` different from `11` and remove them form original array

```
var json = JObject.Parse(jsonString);

foreach (var asset in json["assets"])
{
    var productsArray = asset["products"] as JArray;
    if (productsArray == null)
        continue;

    var productsToRemove = productsArray
        .Where(o => o?["id"]?.Value<int>() != 11)
        .ToList();

    foreach (var product in productsToRemove) 
        productsArray.Remove(product);
}

Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Comment: @SanjayV Does it answer your question, do you need more details or information?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `Select` and Applying a, `Where` try to remove the Products that you do not want.

Following is a sample code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var json = @"
                {
                    'assets': [
                    {
                    'name': 'abc',
                    'products': [
                        {
                        'id': '11',
                        'status': true
                        },
                        {
                        'id': '14',
                        'status': null
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                    'name': 'xyz',
                    'products': [
                        {
                        'id': '11',
                        'status': true
                        },
                        {
                        'id': '28',
                        'status': null
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                    'name': '123',
                    'products': [
                        {
                        'id': '48',
                        'status': null
                        }
                    ]
                    },
                    {
                    'name': '456',
                    'products': [
                        {
                        'id': '11',
                        'status': true
                        }
                    ]
                    }
                ]}";

            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
            var assets = root.Assets;
            assets.ForEach(a =>
            {
                a.Products.RemoveAll(p => p.Id != 11);
            });
        }
    }

    public partial class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("assets")]
        public List<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Asset
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("products")]
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Product
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public bool? Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter the list, you will need to create a new list with products whose ID == YourId. Following linq query does the necessary steps to create the list you want.

1. Filter out any assets that dont have any product with ID == 11. This is necessary to skip nulls in the new list that will be generated (`Where` statement)
2. Create a collection / list of new assets that only have the products whose ID == 11 (`Select` statement)

```
var list = assets.Where(x => x.Products.Where(y => y.Id.Equals("11")).Count() > 0)
                    .Select(asset => { 
                        return new Asset() { 
                            Name = asset.Name, 
                            Products = asset.Products.Where(x => x.Id == "11").ToList() 
                            }; 
                    }).ToList();

// Create the RootObject that holds a list of all the arrays if you want.
Rootobject newAssetCollection = new Rootobject() { Assets = list };
```

Below is the Json that was printed

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newAssetCollection, Formatting.Indented));

{
  "assets": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "status": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "xyz",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "status": true
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "456",
      "products": [
        {
          "id": "11",
          "status": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```